# Way to test ssh connection

Tags: ssh

To test ssh connection, https://help.github.com/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection/ says

```
ssh -T git@github.com
# Attempts to ssh to GitHub
```

the manpage of `ssh` says

```
-T      Disable pseudo-tty allocation.
```

I wonder what the option `-T` means and how it helps to test ssh connection?

Thanks.

Comment: I remember reading a wealth of information on this option the other day, all of it from the Stack Exchange network.  Some on U&L, some on ServerFault.  Did you try googling around?  (If so, you might include links to the more interesting/helpful pages you found, and then specify how those fail to answer your question; i.e. show you've done some research.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900760/what-is-pseudo-tty-allocation-ssh-and-github

Answer (score 2):

The `-T` switch does not test connection. It does only what is mentioned in the manual page (it is also useful for non-interactive sessions). The command just says:

> Connect to `github.com` and do not try to allocate PTY (it is most probably not allowed anyway on the server). Having working `ssh` is just a good prerequisite to have `git` working.

It would work on most of the server also only with `ssh github.com`, but as mentioned in the linked question on SO, some (broken) servers might not deal with it well (or might have not) and we were left with this convention to test `git` connections.

Comment: thanks. is it correct that `-T` is used only for running batch jobs on ssh server?

Comment: basically yes...

Comment: 1. Then is the command for a batch job specified in the ssh command? 2. I remember there is a different way to run batch job on ssh server, and  it has the command for a batch job specified in the ssh command, but seems not using `-T`. I don't remember exactly how this different way is specified without using `-T`, and do you happen to know about that?

Comment: It was `sftp -b` switch. For `ssh` always when you run `ssh` with command, it will be running without PTY on remote side. This switch does not have many reasonable use cases.